# How to access values of row_major matrix in shaders using shader storage blocks?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I want to access value of row_major matrix mat2x4  from compute shader using shader storage block, but always getting wrong result. Getting correct result for mat2, mat3 and mat4. 
my shader as follows. Using glsl430 version.

```
layout(std140, row_major) buffer BufferMat{

mat2 row_mat2;
mat3 row_mat3;
mat4 row_mat4;
mat2x4 row_mat24;
}

void main()
{
row_mat2=mat2(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
row_mat3=mat3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0, 5.0, 6.0,  7.0, 8.0, 9.0);
row_mat4=mat4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0,  9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,  13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0);

row_mat24=mat2x4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0);
}
```

Using glGetProgramResourceIndex, glShaderStorageBlockBinding, and glGetProgramResourceiv to get buffer block index and bind it. Getting the index and value of BUFFER_VARIABLE as follows.

```
index=glGetProgramResourceIndex(progId, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, "row_mat24");

glGetProgramResourceiv(progId, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, index, 3, &prop[1],3* sizeof(GLsizei), &length, params);
fbuffer = (float*)glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, params[0], 4, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
```

'prop'  has value GLenum prop[4]={GL_BUFFER_DATA_SIZE, GL_OFFSET, GL_TYPE, GL_MATRIX_STRIDE}; Getting value as:

```
printf("1 type = mat24 Value =%f %f %f %f", *(fbuffer), *(fbuffer+1), *(fbuffer+2), *(fbuffer+3));

printf("2 type = mat24 Value =%f %f %f %f", *(fbuffer+4), *(fbuffer+5), *(fbuffer+6), *(fbuffer+7));
```

result :

```
1 type = mat24 Value =5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 8.000000
2 type = mat24 Value =1.000000 2.000000 -0.000000 0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

What possible reason do you have for doing `sizeof (params [1])`? That will always return **4** or **8** on most systems depending on the size the compiler uses for `int`. `sizeof` operates on types at compile-time, it does not evaluate expressions at run-time. So as far as `sizeof` is concerned, `sizeof (params [1])` means: *"I had an integer pointer, then I used an array subscript to change the expression to an integer ... what is the size of an integer?"* You might as well replace that with `sizeof (int)` because it means the same thing. You are not mapping enough memory to read more than one or two floating-point values as a result.

What is more, since you overwrite the pointer that stored the memory you allocated one line earlier by the mapped address, you are also creating an unrecoverable memory leak.

Comment: Yes, u are right. But even after removing malloc and allocating enough memory of 8*4.Its giving the same value .Is there any specific way to read the row matrix values?